# BatchSave in DynamoDB is not working

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have created an entry in the dynamoDB with a hash key = "ABC" and with some other attributes as well.

Now when I do a batchSave of 2 items having the same hash key "ABC" with other attributes as different, it is not doing anything.

What is the issue for this ?

Answer (score 0):

The hash key value must be **unique** in the table. The table can't have two items with same hash key value unless you have defined the table with hash key (i.e. partition key) and sort key.

> Partition key – A simple primary key, composed of one attribute known
>   as the partition key.
>
> DynamoDB uses the partition key's value as input to an internal hash
>   function. The output from the hash function determines the partition
>   (physical storage internal to DynamoDB) in which the item will be
>   stored.
>
> In a table that has only a partition key, no two items can have the
>   same partition key value.
>
> The People table described in Tables, Items, and Attributes is an
>   example of a table with a simple primary key (PersonID). You can
>   access any item in the People table immediately by providing the
>   PersonId value for that item.
>
> Partition key and sort key – Referred to as a composite primary key,
>   this type of key is composed of two attributes. The first attribute is
>   the partition key, and the second attribute is the sort key.
>
> DynamoDB uses the partition key value as input to an internal hash
>   function. The output from the hash function determines the partition
>   (physical storage internal to DynamoDB) in which the item will be
>   stored. All items with the same partition key are stored together, in
>   sorted order by sort key value.

Comment: Yeah my table has one hash key only but what if in the batchSave call I have two rows to update with the same hash key. Will it perform the batchSave operation or not ?

Comment: @mshikher It won't. "DynamoDB rejects the entire batch write operation" if "You try to perform multiple operations on the same item [...]". https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/AbstractDynamoDBMapper.html#batchSave-java.lang.Iterable-